# Producing small tables - help how to make it larger?

Tags: tables

I am using this site https://www.tablesgenerator.com/latex_tables

and it produces only small tables..

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}
\cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
1                       & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0}  \\ \hline
1                       & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{10} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

It looks very very small on overleaf:

[image]

And even more, it is not centralized on the page, it puts it in this awkward positioning ~at the middle (tending to the left) while there is a blank space, I want to to be centralized at the top (maybe couple of pixels down, not all the way up)

How do I do it? I tried scalebox[1.7]{ -TABLE- } but it did not work...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What exactly does "Make it larger" refer to here? Do you want to increase the font size or the width and height of the table while keeping the font size as it currently is?

Comment: @leandriis scaling everything up by a couple of magnitudes, it is really small, like very noticeable unsymmetric to the whole page.. I used \center above the table and it looks like it did something, but again the size is really small, not nice looking at all

Comment: Depending on the font size you would like to achive, you could add `\large`, `\Large`or `\LARGE` between `\begin{table}` and `\begin{tabular}` to increase the font size of all text inside of the table.

Comment: And add also `\centering` at the same place

Comment: Hey, \Large and Largest etc is exactly what I needed, but just for future cases- is there a way to scale it by my own size? like x0.4, x1.7, x2.1 etc..  - about \centering - is there a way to center it my way? centring sets it exactly in the center, and I want it to be a couple  of more lines above ... thank you both btw!

Comment: Apart from chosing a different font size, there are ways to scale content by an arbitrary factor, but this will lead to inconsistent font sizes throughout a document and is thus note really recommended. Regarding `\centering`: This command only influences the horizontal position of the table on the page, it does not necessarily result in vertically centered contents.

Comment: @leandriis How should I center my table nicely in the page? I want it to be at the top, not "so" top but in the center of the page. Then I can't do it?

Comment: I also want the text inside to be centralized inside the boxes

Comment: Are there other contents in your document, apart from the table? Also what does "centralized inside the boxes" refer to? Vertically centered of horizontally centerd? If the latter, use `c` type column instead of `l`.

Comment: If you want the table vertically centered on a page, use `\begin{table}[p]...`

Answer (score 1):

Here will show a couple of ways of expanding the cells (and thus the whole table), without enlarging the font.

(The package `float` allows to put the table in the place you want using `[H]`. Now goes to the top of the page because there is no text before; `\centering` will center horizontally in page. Use `\vspace*` before to lower it down)

[image: wer]

If you want to see what happens with a larger font, put `\Large` after `\centering` in the last table. The cells will expand accordingly.

This is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}
        \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
        1                       & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5                       \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0}  \\ \hline
        1                       & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5                       \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{10} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Using centering and [H] (float package)}
\end{table}

\vspace*{20pt}  

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6} %separate the rows.
\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|l|l}
    \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
    1                       & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5                       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{0}  \\ \hline
    1                       & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5                       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{10} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Using arraystretch (calc package)}
\end{table}

\vspace*{20pt}  

\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{4ex}} % wider cells

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.9} %separate the rows.
\begin{tabular}{L|L|L|L|L}
    \cline{2-2} \cline{4-4}
    1                       & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5                       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{0}  \\ \hline
    1                       & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5                       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{6} & 7 & 8 & 9 & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\caption{Using arraystretch and wider cells}
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

`\arraystretch`  adds vertical space, making the cells airier, but since the width of the columns is its natural width, the last column is wider. In a real table you might want to control also the width of the cells, specifying each column width or making all them the same, as here.

Comment: Use of the `H` position specifier should be only desperate effort of last resort in figures placement. It prevent `figure` (and `table`) to float. Far better is to use `htb` or `htbp` specifiers.

Comment: True. But the OP did not wanted a float "(maybe couple of pixels down, not all the way up)" so perhaps  `vspace*` plus `H` does the job.

Comment: No. The approach is wrong. LaTeX is not a Word. What will OP say, when using `H` will find a empty space at bottom of page in size almost of size the figure? OK, iit is up to OP, if (s)he like to have a bad looking document(s).